# How to make a button's width match parent while there is an ImageView on its right in a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

So this is what it looks right now.
[image]

with the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint" />

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/crime_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_title"
        android:text="@string/crime_details_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/suspect_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_solved"
        android:text="@string/choose_suspect" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_crime_report"
        android:text="@string/send_crime_report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/suspect_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/callImage"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/suspect_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/suspect_button"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to do is, have the ImageView `callImage` be on the right of `suspect_button` and in the rightmost side overall. For this, I want the `suspect_button` to be extended as much as possible, just like you do in `match_parent`. But when I do `match_parent` the ImageView gets lost. So to put it simply, I want to "`match_parent`" the `suspect_button` but also have my ImageView `callImage` on the right side of the `suspect_button` while not getting lost in appearance.

I would appreciate it if you do not suggest solutions which require me to use another layout. I want to learn if it is possible, or how to do what I imagine to do in Relative Layout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need add `callImage` `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and add `suspect_button` `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/callImage"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint" />

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/crime_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_title"
        android:text="@string/crime_details_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/suspect_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/callImage"
        android:text="@string/choose_suspect" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_crime_report"
        android:text="@string/send_crime_report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/suspect_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/callImage"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/suspect_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So result will like this
[image]

Answer for question in comment. I need add LinearLayout to make ImageView align right half of screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint" />

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/crime_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_title"
        android:text="@string/crime_details_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_below="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/suspect_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_solved"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/suspect_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/choose_suspect" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/callImage"
                android:layout_width="57dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_crime_report"
        android:text="@string/send_crime_report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/suspect_button_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It will show like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey man you have to try LinearLayout and set its android:layout_weight="5" in both the elements! That will distribute both elements in equal part!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_crime_report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="sdfsdfsd" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/callImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does work. But I dont understand why 5 means that both elements will have equal parts

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different way to achieve this than Tung Duong's answer:

1.Align `callImage` `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
2.Make `suspect_button` `layout_width` to `match_parent`
and add `layout_marginRight` to `suspect_button` exactly as width of `callImage`( i.e. 57dp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout_toLeftOf in your *suspect_button* and pass in the id of the *callImage*. That way your button will take the width of the screen but will room for the image.